# Physic body does not follow PathModifier

Tags: android, andengine

I have a sprite with a body. I would like to move the sprite by a path. I have tried doing this with a PathModifier and the sprite moves as it should but it's body does not follow the sprites position.

Can I move the sprite and the body together? Do I really have to compute velocities for the path and apply that to the body object, because that seems quite hard?

The sprite is initialized like this

```
  ...
  this.sprite = new Sprite(this.x, this.y, textureRegion);
  this.rectangleBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(
        physicsWorld,
        this.sprite,
        BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody,
        this.fixtureDef);
  pPhysicsConnector = new PhysicsConnector(this.sprite, rectangleBody, true, false);
  physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(pPhysicsConnector);
  scene.attachChild(this.sprite);
```

and then later moved with this code

```
     Shape shape = entity.getShape();
     Float[] reverseXPath = ArrayUtils.clone(xPath.toArray(new Float[xPath.size()]));
     ArrayUtils.reverse(reverseXPath);
     Float[] reverseYPath = ArrayUtils.clone(yPath.toArray(new Float[yPath.size()]));
     ArrayUtils.reverse(reverseYPath);
     SequenceEntityModifier oneSequence = new SequenceEntityModifier(
           new PathModifier(
                 duration,
                 new PathModifier.Path(
                       ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(xPath.toArray(new Float[xPath.size()])),
                       ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(yPath.toArray(new Float[yPath.size()]))),
                 IEaseFunction.DEFAULT),
           new PathModifier(
                 duration,
                 new PathModifier.Path(
                       ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(reverseXPath),
                       ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(reverseYPath)),
                 IEaseFunction.DEFAULT));
     shape.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(oneSequence));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find this post useful

http://www.andengine.org/forums/post28936.html

Answer (score 0):

move sprite by path, update body in this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() 
like here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122813/2233069